Formatos de fecha distintos en SharePoint List
Tengo un SharePoint List con las siguientes columnas y tipos de dato:
Title:  Una sola línea de texto
Date:  Una sola línea de texto
EndDate: Una sola línea de texto
Time: Una sola línea de texto
Los datos de esta SharePoint List se introducen automáticamente mediante una PowerApps.
Sin embargo, cuando veo los datos registrados en las columnas Date y EndDate, me aparecen fechas con distintos formatos.
A continuación, muestro algunos ejemplos:

4 marzo 2024
3/12/2024
11/03/2024
April 5, 2024

Es importante que tenga estas fechas con el mismo formato ya que a posteriori existe un dashboard en Power BI que lee los datos de esta SharePoint List. Podría parsear alguna fecha pero existen estas cuatro casuísticas y creo que lo mejor seria solucionar el problema de origen.
Gracias

Tú problema es que esos campos son texto... Si el dato que envía la app es un tipo fecha cambia esos campos en la lista Sharepoint por campos de tipo fecha. Así la carga de datos en la lista se hará como debe hacerse.

Tienes toda la razón! Gracias
